# Primefaces DragDropEvent on JSF UIComponent returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean, uicomponents

I am trying to use primefaces drag and drop on a `UIComponent` but the `DragDropEvent` returns `NullPointerException`. What am I probably doing wrong.

```
@Named(value = "dynaComponentController")
@RequestScoped
```

public class DynaComponentController {

```
private UIComponent component = new HtmlPanelGroup();
private boolean checker = false;


public void onComponentDrop(DragDropEvent event) {
    component = event.getComponent();
    int i = component.getChildCount();
    if(i > 0){
        checker = true;
    }
}
```

My View is

```
<h:form prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup id="drop" layout="block" style="height:150px; width:300px;" styleClass="ui-widget-content">
            <p> Drop Here </p>
            <p:droppable for="drop" onDrop="#{dynaComponentController.onComponentDrop(event)}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <br />

        <h:panelGroup id="drag" layout="block" style="height:150px;width:300px;" binding="#{dynaComponentController.component}">
            <h:outputLabel value="Drag Me" rendered="#{dynaComponentController.checker == false}"/>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{dynaComponentController.checker == true}">
                <h:inputTextarea id="complainID" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <p:draggable for="drag"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.morph.bean.DynaComponentController.onComponentDrop(DynaComponentController.java:38)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)

at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.ja
```

Please the idea to drag a panel onto another panel using primefaces drag and drop feature. On-drop, I want the inputTextArea to be displayed. 
Please if there is a better way to go about this I will appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.
`onDrop` expects a **client**-side callback. You can only use a JavaScript function here. Placing a Bean method here will just call it (with an undefined "event", thus `null`) just the same as if you would have placed `#{dynaComponentController.onComponentDrop(event)}` outside of a tag.

You might consider calling a bean method via a `p:remoteCommand` and wrap that call in a javascript function you call from `onDrop`.

Comment: Thank.  Please do you have any recommendation for the latter part of the question.(display inputtextarea ondrop)

Comment: Hmm, why dont you just handle the event completely on client side? E.g. remove the `rendered` attribute and add a `style="display:none"` and an id instead. Then just do something like `onDrop="$('#theid').css('display','inline');"` .